# How to make trigger click event work after turning off event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a card whose click should be disabled for 3 secs and after 3 secs a click event should trigger on that card which isn't working.

```
$('#card').off('click');

setTimeout(function () {
    $('#card').on('click');
    $('#card').trigger('click');        
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

`On` and `Off` in Jquery event delegation are for a very different purpose, For your requirement add a disabled property to the `card` to prevent users from clicking it and trigger click using `setTimeout`

```
 $('#card').prop('disabled','disabled');

 setTimeout(function () {
    $('#card').removeProp('disabled');
    $('#card').trigger('click');        
 }, 3000);
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example